# HashTable (search function)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "list.cpp"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct HashEntry{
   int key;
   List<string> list;
   HashEntry(int k)
   {        
         key=k;
   } 
}; 

class Hash{
  private:
         HashEntry *Table[100];
         int a;
  public:
         Hash(int A);
         void insert(string word);
         void Lookup(string word);
};    

Hash::Hash(int A)
{
    a=A;
}         

void Hash::insert(string word)
{
   int c=0;
   for (int i=0;i<word.size();i++)
   {                                 
       int b=(int)((a^i)*(word[i]));
       c+=b;
   }
   c%=100;
   List<string> list;
   if (Table[c-1]==NULL)     //if the respective bucket doesnot have any string
   Table[c-1]=new HashEntry(c-1);

   Table[c-1]->list.insertAtTail(word);
}                  


void Hash::Lookup(string word)
{
   int c=0;
   for (int i=0;i<word.size();i++)
   {                                 
     int b=(int)((a^i)*(word[i]));
     c+=b;
   }
   cout<<"one"<<endl;
   c%=100;
   Table[c-1]->list.searchFor(word);
   cout<<"two"<<endl;
}
```

I am making a hash table using seperate chaining taking.my hash function is making a polynomial equation using a constant 'a' whose power is increasing with the index of the letter in a word.(a^0xb+a^1xb+a^2xb+...) , where b is a letter in the word which is being hashed and then I take mod(100) of the final answer.The problem i am facing is in lookup function.when I test the lookup function,the searchFor() function which is in part of part Linked list class does not work although it works fine on its own and i get an segmentation fault after the cout<<"one" which i used to debug .I am sorry for bothering but I just can't understand the problem here.The linked list class file is below.I am just pasting the function in which i am having problem

```
#ifndef __LIST_H
#define __LIST_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
/* This class just holds a single data item. */
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
   vector<string> words;
   T value;
   ListItem<T> *next;
   ListItem<T> *prev;

   ListItem(T theVal)
   {
       this->value = theVal;
       this->next = NULL;
       this->prev = NULL;
   }
};

/* This is the generic List class */
template <class T>
class List
 {
 ListItem<T> *head;

 public:
  // Constructor
  List();

  // Copy Constructor
  List(const List<T>& otherList);

  // Destructor
  ~List();

  // Insertion Functions
  void insertAtHead(T item);
  void insertAtTail(T item);
  void insertAfter(T toInsert, T afterWhat);
  void insertSorted(T item);
  void printList();
  // Lookup Functions
  ListItem<T> *getHead();
  ListItem<T> *getTail();
  void *searchFor(T item);

  // Deletion Functions
  void deleteElement(T item);
  void deleteHead();
  void deleteTail();

  // Utility Functions
  int length();
};

#endif

template <class T>
void List<T>::searchFor(T item)
{    
 ListItem<T> *temp=head;
 if (temp!=NULL)
 {
    while (temp->next!=NULL)
    {
         T sample=temp->value;
         if (sample==item)
         {      
             cout<<"String found";   
             return;
         }
         temp=temp->next;
    }
    T s=temp->value;
    if (s==item)
    {
       cout<<"String found";        
       return;
    }
  }                   
}
```

Comment: "*the searchFor() function does not work although it works fine on its own.*"  Can you elaborate on what that means?

Comment: Do you know that `^` is a xor operator?

Comment: A space after your periods will make your question more readable.

Comment: Uhm, in C++ the `^` refers to the [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation, not exponentiation.

Comment: @DrewDormann On its own mean if I make a seperate linked list and use the searchFor() function,it works fine

Comment: Thanks for pointing the ^ mistake.didn't notice it

Comment: Can you provide some code that works, and some code that doesn't work?

Comment: @user1777067: look at your `Hash::insert` carefully, and think about what will happen if two words hash to the same bucket. Also think carefully about what will happen if you call `Hash::Lookup` for a word that doesn't exist.

Comment: @NikBougalis in Hash::insert, if there is collision,the words get stored in the linked list.thats what i think will happen,won't it?

Comment: No. Look more carefully.

Comment: @user1777067 is the correct bucket `Table[c]` or `Table[c-1]`?  Copying and pasting blobs of code is a great source for errors.  Put that code in its own function.

Comment: @NikBougalis  oh a new bucket is being formed every time but it still is not solving the problem if i add a 'if condition' which is this "if (Table[c-1]==NULL)".sorry i m a little slow in understanding and realising stuff

Comment: @DrewDormann  Table[c-1] is the correct one.

Comment: @user1777067: right a new bucket will always be created. But that's *not* the only bug. You can look a bit more carefully (Hint: *where do the bucket pointers point initially?*) or you can look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment above, which led you to find one of the bugs you have, I will add this:

The reason why you crash is that your `Hash` class mismanages the hash table. First of all, you allocate an array of 100 `HashEntry` pointers:

```
HashEntry *Table[100];
```

Notice that you never set those pointers to anything - so they're pointing to who knows what. Perhaps they will, by sheer luck, point to NULL, but the chances of that are miniscule - you're way way way more likely to win the lottery. So, you are accessing some  random memory - and that's **bad**.

The solution to that is to set each entry to `NULL` explicitly using a loop in your constructor. You will also need a destructor to free any allocated entries, so that you can `delete` it and not leak memory, because leaking is bad.

But an interesting question is why do it like that at all? Why not simply declare the buckets like this:

```
HashEntry Table[100];
```

That way all your buckets are allocated as part of the `Hash` object and you don't have to worry about dynamically allocating and deallocating buckets, checking pointers for `NULL` etc.

One problem with doing that is that your `HashEntry` constructor requires an `int` argument. It's unclear why that argument is necessary; I don't think that you need it and and you could just remove it.

This *one* change would have simplified your code dramatically and eliminated three bugs and the crash.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice.I am really grateful.i really suck at programming.

Comment: We all sucked at some point - don't get discouraged. Practice is the key. Practice with writing code. Practice with debugging code. Practice with re-designing code.